# Android. Date Picker (spinner) doesn't display properly

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I initialize my date picker as follows:

```
    if (question.getAnswers().size() > 0) {
        EBotAnswer ans = question.getAnswers().get(0);

        try {
            if (ans.hasMinDate()) {
                picker.setMinDate(ans.getMinDateInLocalDate().getTimeInMillis());
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
        try {
            if (ans.hasMaxDate()) {
                picker.setMaxDate(ans.getMaxDateInLocalDate().getTimeInMillis());
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }

        Calendar startWithDate = null;
        if (ans.hasStartWithDate()) {
            startWithDate = ans.getStartWithDateInLocalDate();
        } else if (ans.defaultCalendarDateMin()) {
            startWithDate = ans.getMinDateInLocalDate();
        } else if (ans.defaultCalendarDateMax()) {
            startWithDate = ans.getMaxDateInLocalDate();
        } else if (ans.defaultCalendarDateStartWith()) {//This is somewhat redundant
            startWithDate = ans.getStartWithDateInLocalDate();
        }
        if (startWithDate != null) {
            picker.updateDate(
                    startWithDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    startWithDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    startWithDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
    }
```

But initially, the layout looks like so:

[image]

If I start turning the day spinner, the 8th of July shows up.
[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening ?!

I tried calling `picker.invalidate()` or `picker.requestLayout()` or even `picker.requestFocus()` but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What is value of startWithDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ?

Comment: Very, very good point ! Let me check !

Comment: Yeah, that's it ! The set date is June 20th 2018. It's way beyond the max value. That's how it comes from the webservice. Can you please make an answer out of your comment so I can accept it please? Greatly appreciate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `startWithDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`. It may not valid for the cases which you applied to DatePicker, like max range.

To handle it properly, you can show minimum date or maximum date in case of input is out-of-range

```
if (startWithDate != null
        && (startWithDate.getTimeInMillis() < picker.getMaxDate())
        && (startWithDate.getTimeInMillis() > picker.getMinDate())) {
    picker.updateDate(
            startWithDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            startWithDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            startWithDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
} else {
    // In case of invalid date set it to minimum
    startWithDate.setTimeInMillis(picker.getMinDate());
    // Or if you want to set it to maximum
    // startWithDate.setTimeInMillis(picker.getMaxDate());
    picker.updateDate(
            startWithDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            startWithDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            startWithDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't work, still. Now the DAY_OF_MONTH is 8, year 2000 and MONTH is 6, and it has the same issue. Hmm...

Comment: @AndreiBogdan Ok one more analysis please. Log values of picker.setMinDate(ans.getMinDateInLocalDate().getTimeInMillis()); and picker.setMaxDate(ans.getMaxDateInLocalDate().getTimeInMillis()); also. To verify these all 3 behaviours. I am sure date is going beyond

Comment: The min value is -1622918782717, the calendar says July 29th 1918 ... which is proper. The max millis is set to 963033217287 and the startWithDate is set to 963033209868

Comment: Android accepts unix timestamp. So for dates before 1 Jan 1970 it may not work. Try once hardcoding it to 1 Jan 1970 (min value), and then let me know

Comment: I put the minimum value at 09/23/1988 590965200000 .. but nope ... still doesn't display the 8 ... what...is...going...on !

Comment: Let me try at my side. Which API you are using?

Comment: target and compile 26, min 21

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174317/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-andreibogdan).

Comment: I'm getting the same problem while changing month in the spinner. The day becomes disappeared when month is changed!

Comment: @VishnuSP Are doing anything on change of month? If yes please create one question here with code.

Comment: @PankajKumar I don't do anything while changing month. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530726/android-datepicker-in-spinner-mode-not-showing-date-when-launched : Here is my question