# Android DatePicker in spinner mode not showing date

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I'm using `DatePicker` in spinner mode, and sets min and max limit. Then updates the date as max value. Date column does not have a value when the `DatePickerDialog` shown. When I tap/scroll up or down the values are shown.

**MyLayout:**

```
         <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/date_picker"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_default"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_default"
                android:datePickerMode="spinner"
                android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

**Java Part :** (in `onViewCreated`)

```
 private static final int DATE_PICKER_MONTH_OFFSET = 1;
 private static final int DATE_PICKER_MIN_DATE_OFFSET_IN_MIN = 1;

datePicker.setMinDate( now().minusMinutes( 
         DATE_PICKER_MIN_DATE_OFFSET_IN_MIN).getMillis() );
datePicker.setMaxDate( activationDateTime.getMillis() );
datePicker.updateDate( activationDateTime.getYear(), 
         activationDateTime.getMonthOfYear() - DATE_PICKER_MONTH_OFFSET,
                    activationDateTime.getDayOfMonth() );
```

**Problematic Screenshot:**

[image]

What more is needed to make the date part to be displayed when the `DatePickerDialog` is shown?

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

The seems that picker show an empty view when the value set is same as the max limit. I could resolve the issue (while launching the `DatePicker`) by placing `datePicker.updateDate` first and then call `datePicker.setMaxDate`. The `setMaxDate` will validate the previously value and sets correctly. 
But now I face the same problem when I scroll the month from Jul to Aug, the day view becomes empty!

Any solution/suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `now().minusMinutes( 
         DATE_PICKER_MIN_DATE_OFFSET_IN_MIN).getMillis() );` (`now()`) and after an older time than less is sure than now so this can create bug. If you take time and the app need more than one min they will crash. I suggest you use `activationDateTime` instead of `now()`

Comment: I need the spinner from system date to activation date. That's why `now()` is used. And I don't face any problem with the min. Problem happens when the Max value is updated as current to the `DatePicker`

Comment: In the `min` value? and `activationDateTime` is in the futur or past compare to `now()`

Comment: yes, `activationDateTime` is in future which is set as max. Also updating the same as current date to show when picker is launched.

Comment: @VishnuSP I think it is going beyond the max limit of picker when you set month as Aug. What is your max date?

Comment: Why don't you post full code with `activationDateTime` declaration and assignment?

Comment: @PankajKumar Max date is 1533189687213 (2018-08-02T11:31:27.213+05:30). This is shown correctly when launched. I slide up and change to July, SLide down to Aug again the day is empty as shown in the image

Comment: @mTak activationDateTime is received as an argument to the fragment in millisec. format which is converted to `DateTime`

Comment: Is this org.joda.time.DateTime or a custom class?

Comment: ya, It's `org.joda.time.DateTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to have bug in the android widget `DatePicker` in the `spinner` mode. Already such a ticket present in the Google issue tracker also : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64508670

Unfortunately no work around or suggestions available in the issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Solved it like that:

```
 datePicker.init(initYear, initMonthOfYear, initDayOfMonth,
            new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
                    int id = res.getIdentifier("day", "id", "android");
                    NumberPicker dayPicker = datePicker.getRootView().findViewById(id);
                    if (dayPicker != null) {
                        id = res.getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id", "android");
                        TextView inputText = dayPicker.findViewById(id);
                        if (inputText != null && TextUtils.isEmpty(inputText.getText())) {
                            inputText.setText(String.valueOf(dayPicker.getValue()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```